# Receive 404 error from url in Android

Tags: android, url, http-status-code-404

I want receive the 404 error from url, but the code that I use always produce an error:

```
public String getRespond(String request) {

    try{
        URL url=new URL (request);
        URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
        InputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(in);
        String response=scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        return response;

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

the error is in the "in = new ...", and is impossible for me know if there is the 404 error. 
This is the error:

```
02-23 11:42:42.869  20413-20413/com.mappleapps.tm2ibz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mappleapps.tm2ibz, PID: 20413
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the error? You should provide `LogCat` output so we can help you

Comment: To check if there is a 404 error you should use connection.getResponseCode() before the input stream, and it will return the number of the response (such as 200, 400, 404...)

Comment: @Gorcyn Sorry, I have edited the post with the error! Thanks!

Comment: You need to call the method from another Thread, because you cannot do Network calls from main Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests are no longer allowed on the main thread of the application.

So you should use a parallel `Thread`, or more simply an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class ResponseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public static interface ResponseTaskListener {
        void onResponse(String response);
        void onException(Exception e);
    }

    private ResponseTaskListener listener;
    private Exception e;

    public ResponseTask(ResponseTaskListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String request = urls[0];

            URL url=new URL (request);
            URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
            InputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            Scanner scanner =new Scanner(in);
            String response=scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.close();
            return response;

        } catch (Exception e){
            this.e = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    // String response = what is returned by doInBackground
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (this.listener != null) {
            if (this.e != null) {
                this.listener.onException(this.e);
            } else {
                this.listener.onResponse(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to execute this request, you can just:

```
new ResponseTask(new ResponseTaskListener() {
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Play with the response
    }
    public void onException(Exception e) {
        // Play with the exception
    }
}).execute(urlToRssFeed);
```

Comment: When I use this code, in the InputStream in = new... always entry in the catch exception, and response is null.

Comment: What do you get in the `LogCat` if you add `Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);` in the `catch` block